# Bourne shell build string and use it as param

Tags: linux, shell, build, var

I am using bourne shell and want to do the following:

```
COUNTER=0
CIRCLEPART1="|"
CIRCLEPART2="/"
CIRCLEPART3="--"
CIRCLEPART4='\'

while [ $COUNTER -lt 3 ]; do
    ACT_CIRCLEPART=CIRCLEPART$COUNTER
    echo "Hello `eval \${ACT_CIRCLEPART}`"
    COUNTER=`expr $COUNTER + 1`
done
```

I've wanted to adress one of the CIRCLE-names in each loop. I've found a code snippet on stackoverflow but it also doesn't work because my output is "Hello, 8537{myConstructedVar}.":

```
FOOCOUNT=4
FOO_0=John
FOO_1=Barry
FOO_2=Lenny
FOO_3=Samuel
count=$FOOCOUNT
counter=0
while [ $counter -lt $count ]
do
    myConstructedVar=FOO_$counter
    counter=`expr $counter + 1`
    echo "Greeting #$counter: Hello, `eval echo \$${myConstructedVar}`."
done
```

Thanks for any help. Greetings.

Comment: Are you actually using the Bourne shell, or just `/bin/sh` on your machine (which may actually be a link to another shell such as `dash` or `bash` running in POSIX compatibility mode)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have plain old `sh` to test it with (I have tried `bash --posix`), but this might do the job:

```
COUNTER=0
CIRCLEPART1="|"
CIRCLEPART2="/"
CIRCLEPART3="--"
CIRCLEPART4='\'
while [ $COUNTER -lt 3 ]; do
    ACT_CIRCLEPART=CIRCLEPART$COUNTER
    eval echo "Hello \$$ACT_CIRCLEPART"
    COUNTER=`expr $COUNTER + 1`
done
```

Output is:

```
Hello 
Hello |
Hello /
```

This also works in `bash`.

The first line of output refers to `CIRCLEPART0` which is not defined. Correcting for that and running over all defined variables:

```
COUNTER=1
CIRCLEPART1="|"
CIRCLEPART2="/"
CIRCLEPART3="--"
CIRCLEPART4='\'
while [ $COUNTER -lt 5 ]; do
    ACT_CIRCLEPART=CIRCLEPART$COUNTER
    eval echo "Hello \$$ACT_CIRCLEPART"
    COUNTER=`expr $COUNTER + 1`
done
```

Output is:

```
Hello |
Hello /
Hello --
Hello \
```

Comment: The line with `eval` can be simplified to `eval echo "Hello \$$ACT_CIRCLEPART"`.

Comment: So it can, thanks @chepner. I've updated the answer to reflect this simplification.

Answer (score 1):

Use BASH and an array instead:

```
BUSY=("|" "/" "-" "\\\\")
while [[ $COUNTER -lt 4 ]]; do
    printf "Hello ${BUSY[$COUNTER]}\r"
    sleep 0.3
    ((COUNTER ++))
done
echo
```

The odd `\\\\` is necessary because while parsing the line, BASH will reduce this to `\\` since they are used in a double quote. Then `printf` will parse the argument again, reducing that to a single `\`.

Note: Bourne shell is very, very ancient. I doubt that you can find any Unix system today which doesn't at least have KSH. Also, on most Linux systems, `/bin/sh` isn't a pure Bourne shell either.

Comment: If he's really using Bourne shell (or perhaps just POSIX shell), arrays aren't an option.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help... Almost every suggestion worked! I actually use bash. Was thinking I'm using bourne shell because of using the command 'sh someprogram.sh'.